# Sending this parameter in javascript function

Tags: javascript, parameters, this

I have checkbox as below :

```
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="serviceable_check_1" id="serviceable1" name="condition_of_materials[]" onclick="checkOnlyOne(1,obj); return false;" ><span> Serviceable</span></label>
```

And javascript function is :

```
function checkOnlyOne(slno, this) { //Error here 
  console.log(this);
  //$('.serviceable_check_1').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  if(this.checked){
     $('.serviceable_check_1').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  }
}
```

I am getting javascript error as `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this`. How do I send this parameter `onchange` event ?

Comment: Why don't you use radio buttons instead of checkboxes and a function to simulate radio buttons?

Comment: You may want to send "this" in the onclick action (replace obj), and put "obj" in place of "this" in the checkOnlyOne function.  But this code looks a bit strange right now.  And Andreas is right, you may just want radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for the error: you cannot name an argument "this" since it is a reserved word.

Now, "this" refers to its context of execution, thus, the onclick handler is a method of the element,  and therefore will be excecuted in it's context (input element in our case).

Notice the second alert in the snippet, you will see that onclick calls the function you defined from its body, which means that this function we've defined is not a method of the input object element and therefore not "attached" to it and will be called from the context in which it was declared(the window object).

```js
var value = "I'm the value out of the input object";

function displayMessage(context){
  //we save the original context as arg
  alert("input's value: " + context.value);
  alert("the onclick handler:" + context.onclick);
  //but notic that the context has changed
  alert("the context in our function: " + this);
  alert("when trying without saving the previous context: " + this.value);

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="subscribeToNews" value="Newsletter" onclick="displayMessage(this)"/>
<label for="subscribeToNews" >Subscribe </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your *this* does not refer to anything. You can't put *this* on a function unless it is an object or part of the DOM.

You can put the *this* keyword on the element that will trigger the function as an argument. Then on your function, make the parameter a variable like chckbx or radiobtn if those are your elements

```
document.getElementById('mycheckbox').onchange = myFunction(this);

function myFunction(chckbx){
console.log(chckbx);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

see below snippet

```js
function checkOnlyOne(slno, obj) { //Error here 
  console.log(obj);
  //$('.serviceable_check_1').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  if(obj.checked){
     $('.serviceable_check_1').not(obj).prop('checked', false);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="serviceable_check_1" id="serviceable1" name="condition_of_materials[]" onclick="checkOnlyOne(1,this); return false;" ><span> Serviceable</span></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the event object

Serviceable

```
function checkOnlyOne(slno, e {
    console.log(e.target);
    //$('.serviceable_check_1').not(e.target).prop('checked', false);
    if(this.checked)
        $('.serviceable_check_1').not(e.target).prop('checked', false);
}
```

e.target is the element you clicked

Answer (score 1):

You should use .call and pass obj as first parameter to use it as `this` context

```
<input id="serviceable1" onclick="checkOnlyOne.call(obj, 1); return false;" ><span> Serviceable</span></label>
```